# Declaring mutable fields in spring boot rest controller

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, singleton, spring-restcontroller

The following is my Rest Controller:

```
    @RestController
    public class MyController {
    
    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;
    private boolean deprecatedAPICall = false;
    
    @PostMapping(value = "/deprecatedEndPoint", produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<> deprecatedEndPoint(@RequestBody DeprecatedRequestBody deprecatedRequestBody){
        deprecatedAPICall = true;
        NewRequestBody newRequestBody = preProcess(deprecatedRequestBody);
        result = newEndPoint(newRequestBody);
        postProcess(result);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(result)
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/newEndPoint", produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<> newEndPoint(@RequestBody NewRequestBody newRequestBody){
        ...
        if(deprecatedAPICall) {
            deprecatedAPICall = false;
            ...
        }
        result = myService.process(newRequestBody);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(result)
    }
```

Since the Rest Controller is having a singleton scope, is it a good practise to maintain a mutable field (deprecatedAPICall) in this class? What can possibly go wrong in this class in production?

Comment: Multithreading might be an issue, so making it `volatile` ensures that all threads read an updated value. Else, where are you using this field? What is the purpose of it?

Comment: Keep in mind that `volatile` won't prevent race conditions in case something is dependant on `deprecatedAPICall` value.